# Writing a generic wrapper function to rate-limit Promise.allSettled()

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am using the Javascript SDK v3 to submit several API commands in parallel. The general flow is

const client = new SomeAWSClient(config) const response: Promise<SomeAWSClientCommandOutput> = client.send(new SomeAWSClientCommand(input))

I am looking to batch together a group of compatible clients/commands/outputs and wrap them in Promise.allSettled(). I found I can't just invoke allSettled() with a arbitrarily long Promises[]. Once it gets above length=10 or so they will fail. So I would like to write a generic function that can take a valid client and (potentially) lengthy command[] and batch the commands into groups no larger than 10 until they are all fulfilled and then return the results. Here is an example of the logic for a single client/command combination.

```
export async function s3GetObjects(client: S3Client, commands: GetObjectCommand[]) {
    const commandsClone = [...commands];
    const retArr: PromiseSettledResult<GetObjectCommandOutput>[] = [];
    const batchSize = 10;
    let count = 0;
    const promises: Promise<GetObjectCommandOutput>[] = [];
    let command = commandsClone.shift();
    while (command) {
        count += 1;
        if (count <= batchSize) {
            promises.push(client.send(command));
        } else {
            const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
            retArr.push(...result);
            promises.length = 0;
            promises.push(client.send(command));
            count = 1;
        }
        command = commandsClone.shift();
    }
    if (promises.length > 0) {
        const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
        retArr.push(...result);
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

To make it generic, I've tried coming up with three type definitions for valid client/command/output combinations and then a generic function to perform allSettled() call. Here it is without the batchSize=10 logic yet.

```
type ValidClient = S3Client | CloudFormationClient | LambdaClient;

type ValidCommand<T extends ValidClient> = T extends S3Client 
    ? GetObjectCommand | PutObjectCommand
    : T extends CloudFormationClient
    ? DescribeStacksCommand
    : T extends LambdaClient
    ? GetFunctionCommand
    : never;

type ValidCommandOutput<T extends ValidCommand<ValidClient>> = T extends GetObjectCommand
    ? GetObjectCommandOutput
    : T extends PutObjectCommand
    ? PutObjectCommandOutput
    : T extends DescribeStacksCommand
    ? DescribeStacksCommandOutput
    : T extends GetFunctionCommand
    ? GetFunctionCommandOutput : never;

export async function promiseAllSettled<
    TClient extends ValidClient,
    TCommand extends ValidCommand<TClient>,
    TOutput extends ValidCommandOutput<ValidCommand<TClient>>
>(client: TClient, commands: TCommand[]): Promise<PromiseSettledResult<Awaited<TOutput>>[]> {
    const promises: Promise<TOutput>[] = [];
    for (const command of commands) {
        promises.push(client.send(command));
    }
    return Promise.allSettled(promises);
}
```

It seems to work well, preventing invalid input combinations, but I get an error on the send() call that I can't figure out.

```
This expression is not callable.
    Each member of the union type '{ \<InputType extends ServiceInputTypes, OutputType extends
    ServiceOutputTypes\>(command: Command\<ServiceInputTypes, InputType, ServiceOutputTypes, OutputType,
    SmithyResolvedConfiguration\<...\>\>, options?: HttpHandlerOptions | undefined): Promise\<...\>; \<InputType
    extends ServiceInputTypes, OutputType extends ServiceOut...' has signatures, but none of those signatures
    are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Any ideas of good ways to resolve this?